# File contents not being read in nodejs program

Tags: node.js

I have a file temp.js that contains text as below:

```
module.config = {
  key1 : 'value1',
  key2 : 'value2',
  key3 : ['abc','def']

}
```

I am reading the file as below:

```
fs.readFile('/temp.js', function(err,fileContents) {
   console.log(fileContents);
});
```

on the output I am getting values as below:

```
<Buffer 6d 6f .....
...>
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: You're reading the hex contents of the file; it's being read as a binary rather than as a text string. Easy way to tell? In ASCII, all the lowercase letter range starts with 0x61, and the uppercase range starts with 0x41.

Comment: `6d 6f` are the letters `m` and `o`. I'm guessing you want to evaluate the file as Javascript, which... really isn't what you're doing, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for `fs.readFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback):

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

Therefore, if you want a string passed to your callback, specify the encoding of the file. Example:

```
fs.readFile('/temp.js', {encoding: 'utf8'}, function(err, fileContents) {
   console.log(fileContents);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is being read but as `Buffer`. To read it as string you've to tell `fs` the encoding.

Try this

```
require('fs').readFile('/temp.js','utf-8', function(err,fileContents) {
   console.log(fileContents);
});
```